# Node.js stdout flush

Tags: node.js

Maybe I'm duplicating [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471004/how-can-i-write-blocking-in-stdout-with-node-js) question, but the answer provided refers probably to an older version of node (i'm using v0.5.10), because `fs.writeSync(1, "Foo\n");` alone doesn't solve my problem (the output doesn't get flushed when executing the script from a shell script) and `fs.fsyncSync(1);` is [not documented](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/all.html) and when I try it node rises the exception:

```
 return binding.fsync(fd);
             ^
 Error: UNKNOWN, Operation complete;

at Object.fsyncSync (fs.js:353:18)
at Interface.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\Git\org.github.pistacchio.streamcommunication\nodebot.js:36:12)
at Interface.emit (events.js:67:17)
at Interface._onLine (readline.js:162:10)
at Interface._line (readline.js:426:8)
at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:603:14)
at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:82:12)
at ReadStream.emit (events.js:88:20)
at ReadStream._emitKey (tty.js:309:10)
at ReadStream.onData (tty.js:66:12)
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be blocking, an on-flush callback would be enough, right?

Comment: i'm writing a console script, so yes, it should be blocking. for my purpose, all the async calls are more a problem than a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

You want it to be blocking, but I guess [streamlinejs](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs) should work for you, too:

```
var done = process.stdout.write(str);
if (!done) {
  // this effectively means "wait for this
  // event to fire", but it doesn't block everything
  process.stdout.on('drain', _)
}
doSome(otherStuff)
```

You can paste this code [here](http://sage.github.com/streamlinejs/examples/streamlineMe/streamlineMe.html) to see what it will be compiled to when you call it. Also, you'll have to install streamline with `npm install streamline -g`, to put your code in a file which has a name ending with `_.js` and to run your code with `node-streamline filename_`.