# Problems communicating between Node.js and Python via stdio

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, coffeescript, subprocess

I'm spawning a Node process from within a Python thread and passing data between them via stdio. After Python sends something to Node, Node fires up a child process and then sends the output from that child process back to Python.

This works, for a few seconds and then no more data comes. However, if I kill the Node process, then suddenly all of the data comes at once.

I figure this is something to do with buffering but I've tried so many things and can't get it to work properly.

It's worth mentioning that if I run the monitor outside of Python it works fine, so this is probably something on the Python side.

Relevant Python code:

```
class MonitorThread(Thread):
    # *snip*

    def run(self):
        self.process = Popen(['node',
            path.join(PACKAGE_PATH 'monitor.js')],
            stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

        while self.process.poll() is None:
            stdout = self.process.stdout.readline().rstrip('\n')

            if stdout:
                main_thread(debug, stdout)

            stderr = self.process.stderr.readline().rstrip('\n')

            if stderr:
                main_thread(debug, stderr)

            #time.sleep(0.1)
```

Relevant Node.js code (in CoffeeScript but even if you don't know it you get the idea):

```
# *snip*

child = spawn cmd, options

child.stdout.on 'data', (data) ->
    process.stdout.write "stdout: #{data.toString().trim()}\n"

child.stderr.on 'data', (data) ->
    process.stdout.write "stderr: #{data.toString().trim()}\n"
```

There's a lot of other code but it's not really relevant, data is being sent and then afterwards data is being received, just only for a moment. It IS still running as when I kill it manually, the rest of the data suddenly appears.

```
Monitor [send] - {"wrap": false, "directories": {"src": "lib"}, "id": 0, "base_dir": "C:\\Users\\Joe\\Documents\\GitHub\\CoffeeScript-Sublime-Plugin"}
Monitor [recv] - 13:55:30 - compiled src\a.coffee
Monitor [recv] - path.exists is now called `fs.exists`.
Monitor [recv] - 13:55:30 - compiled src\b.coffee
```

- I've tried util.pump()
- I've tried, with the spawn() call, stdio: 'inherit'
- I've tried waiting for the 'drain' event before sending more data.

Comment: It seems that the output is buffered. This may help to prevent buffering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471004/how-can-i-write-blocking-in-stdout-with-node-js

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference, well actually it exacerbates the problem.

Only one line makes it through instead of three and of course nothing comes through when the process is killed now (because of the lack of buffering).

Comment: Seems I still had the stdio: 'inherit'. After removing it, I get: EBADF - bad file descriptor. EDIT: If ran standalong, I get that. If ran from within Python, I get no error but no output.

Answer (score 0):

You should also pass the `end` event to close the streams and have node flush them:

```
child = spawn cmd, options

child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
child.stderr.pipe(process.stdout)

child.stdout.on 'data', (data) ->
    process.stdout.write "stdout: #{data.toString().trim()}\n"

child.stdout.on 'end', () ->
    process.stdout.end()

child.stderr.on 'end', () ->
    process.stdout.end()
```

An even better option would be to use [Stream.pipe()](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipe_destination_options).